# How can I set gradle on windows 10?

Tags: android, gradle

I am persionate and novice in Kotlin.

After downloading android studio, I can't figure out what's going wrong with gradle.

It says: "...Was not found in the following sources"

What should I do? Please help me.

Gradle not isn't working.

Comment: Hi! You have not mentioned what project are you trying to open. Probably it does not contain gradle files at all. Try to create a new project from the Android studio and move your folders into it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.